# FCM.getToken() promise never resolved

Tags: javascript, firebase, notifications, push, messaging

I'm trying to implement web push notifications with FireBase. It works good in desktop chrome/firefox, but when it comes to android I can't get the notification token - the promise, returned from messaging.getToken is never resolved, neither throws an error (always pending). I have a service worker, and it is active and running. Here is my code - what do I do wrong?

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script>
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBuFGsjFDCILwYVzLHWLvoRIHSoDZIQBl8",
    authDomain: "mobilepush-fd2d5.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://mobilepush-fd2d5.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "mobilepush-fd2d5",
    storageBucket: "mobilepush-fd2d5.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "106871298920"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  messaging.usePublicVapidKey("BBYGyuGH2KqQSHyc55Di5IQnHc52fY6gqmExfWtg85-wabmQimja6X6ViR2jmNgPBZBuLeX0BXf9A0yLqUV5m90");
  var curStatus = messaging.getNotificationPermission_();
  if (curStatus == 'granted') {
    messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
      if (currentToken) {
        processToken(currentToken, 1);
      } else {
        reqPerm();
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      //error
    });
  } else if (curStatus == 'denied') {
    //denied
  } else {
    reqPerm();
  }

  function reqPerm() {
    messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
      messaging.getToken().then(processToken);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      //error
    });
  }

  function processToken(token, hasAlready) {
    alert(token);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Just to be sure: did you log something inside your catch functions? Because if you are using the code as is you will not see if the promise got rejected

Comment: I connected android phone to my desktop and used remote debugging function to see, that the promise returned from calling "gettoken" is constantly pending and never resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Found it - the phone memory was absolutely full, so Firebase script couldn't add token data to the local indexeddb of the browser. Deleted some files on device and now it works.